# Use a list in a mutate function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use a list in a mutate, please see below:

```
Grouping <- c('f_risk_code', 'f_risk_category')
Pasting <- c('f_risk_code, f_risk_category')
```

Then using it in here:

```
Nested_Train %>%
  mutate(Category = paste0(glue_col(Pasting), sep='_'))
```

But this is not having the desired effect - it is just returning f_risk_code', 'f_risk_category as the Category instead of the actual risk code and risk category fields. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don’t try to highlight code.

Comment: So are `f_risk_code` and `f_risk_category` columns in your data.frame? What exactly is the desired output? The `glue_col` function is for constructing strings with color. Are you trying to create colors here somehow? What does the version that doesn't use a vector look like? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, they are columns in the Nested_Train - and i want to use them as outputs without stipulating the column names

Comment: If i do the following it does what i want:
Nested_Train %>%
  mutate(Category = paste(f_risk_code, f_risk_category, sep = '_'))

Comment: Try something like: `cols <- rlang::exprs(hp, cyl); mtcars %>% mutate(out=paste(!!!cols, sep="_"))`

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call` :

```
library(dplyr)

Nested_Train %>% mutate(Category = do.call(paste0, .[Pasting]))
```

Comment: Is it possible to mark this as answered??

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `invoke`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
Nested_Train %>%
     mutate(Category = invoke(paste0, .[Pasting]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me:
Try something like:

```
cols <- rlang::exprs(hp, cyl); mtcars %>% mutate(out=paste(!!!cols, sep="_"))
```